# How to accept websocket connections from a NextJS app deployed on vercel. In Django project that is deployed on Ubuntu VPS using nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, next.js, websocket, gunicorn

The devlopment version of my django and nextjs is working fine but when I deployed the nextjs project on vercel and django project on ubuntu vps, It is not working!

My django project uses django-channels to intract with the frontend and send messages thorough websocket.

**Here is my nginx file:**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    server_name _;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/projectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    location /ws {

        proxy_pass http://localhost;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

}
```

**Here is my gunicorn.service file**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/projectdir
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn 
--access-logfile - 
--workers 4 
--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock 
--worker-class=geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker 
chatterboxBackend.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Here is my routing.py file:**

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
re_path(r"^ws/message/(?P<room_name>w+)/$", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),

]
```

**Here is my project's .asgi file**

```
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "chatterboxBackend.settings")
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

import message.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(message.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```

At first when I try to connect to backend websocket using JavaScript, **it says: connection failed...**
But, when I started the gunicorn server with command line then the gunicorn logs say, 'not found /ws/message/'

I asked this problem from ChatGPT and other tools but it is still not working....